# How to run a SQL command within a Bash script and save the output of that command to a variable

Tags: sql, oracle, bash

I am looking to enclose some Oracle components within a Bash script that will perform a set of goals:

1. Log into a remote server (where my Oracle DB resides) as root.
2. Performs an "su - oracle".
3. Logs into sqlplus environment as a specific Oracle user.
4. Performs an SQL select command and stores the output of that command into a variable.
5. Displays the result of that variable in the Bash shell.

I have looked through a couple examples here on stackoverflow, many of which seem to go over executing a command but not necessarily detailing how to display the output to the user (although I am still examining a few more). For example, assuming all key exchanges are setup beforehand, a method could be to use the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh -q root@5.6.7.8
sqlplus ABC/XYZ@core <<ENDOFSQL
select CREATE_DATE from PREPAID_SUBSCRIBER where MSISDN='12345678912';
exit;
ENDOFSQL
```

Instead, here is how I tried to set this up:

```
#!/bin/sh
datasource_name=`echo "select CREATE_DATE from PREPAID_SUBSCRIBER where MSISDN='12345678912';" | ssh -q 5.6.7.8 "su - oracle -c 'sqlplus -S ABC/XYZ@core'" | tail -2 | head -1`
```

Ideally, the datasource_name variable should now either take on values:

```
no rows selected
```

Or if there is an entry within the table:

```
CREATE_DATE
-------------------
07-06-2009 18:04:48
```

The tail and head commands are to get rid of the empty lines in the output, and the ssh -q and sqlplus -S options are for ignoring warnings.

However, when I run that command, and do an:

```
echo "${datasource_name}"
```

I get...

Warning: no access to tty (Bad file descriptor).
Thus no job control in this shell.

...instead of one of the two outputs above. If I understand correctly, this is a warning that can be caused depending on whether a specific shell is used, but most online sources indicate that this can be ignored. The nice thing about this warning is that it appears my command above is actually running and storing "something" into datasource_name, but it just isn't what I want.

Now to simplify this problem, I noticed I get the same tty warning when I simply try to su to oracle on the remote machine from the box where the bash script runs:

```
ssh root@5.6.7.8 "su - oracle"
Warning: no access to tty (Bad file descriptor).
Thus no job control in this shell.
```

If I do the following, I actually get into the sqlplus environment successfully with no issues:

```
ssh -q root@5.6.7.8 "su - oracle -c 'sqlplus ABC/XYZ@core'"
```

> SQL*Plus: Release 9.2.0.4.0 - Production on Tue May 29 12:35:06 2012
>
> Copyright (c) 1982, 2002, Oracle Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> Connected to: Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release
>   10.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
>
> SQL>

If I understand why the problem above is occurring, it is possible that I can figure out how to get my script to work properly. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Why do you ssh as the root (!) user, only to then su to the oracle users? Why not ssh directly as the oracle user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the first line to:

```
ssh -t  root@5.6.7.8 "su - oracle"
```

to get a tty to see if that would work for you.

another thing you can do in your script is to redirect stderr to your variable as well if you would like to see that as well in your variable, which does not appear to be the case for you, though I have done so in the past in some cases. There is an example in the comments below.

Comment: Hello John, unfortunately the -t option did not appear to work, I ended up with the same tty warning. Let me play around with that some more, and I will also see if theglauber's suggestion above will help resolve this, after I get the proper syntax taken care of.

Comment: Ah, ok disregard that previous statement. Now I am getting a new output when using the -t option appropriately: echo "${datasource_name}" gives: With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, OLAP, Data Mining. Clearly it's giving that last part of the login verbiage, so I just need to now get that statement to work.

Comment: Great, I got the output working! Now let me try to do the stderr redirection as you suggested for a clean output. Thanks to all for the suggestions. I can't yet rep you yet but know that your help was appreciated.

Comment: look at the -s option of the sqlplus, it will suppress all information returned normally by sqlplus. For example command: sqlplus -s scott/password@orcl <<<"
set pages 0 feed off;
select * from dual;" will simply return value "X"

Comment: I originally had the -S option and for some reason I took it out!!! I put it back in and clearly now, I am getting only what I need. Thanks.

Comment: Stderr won't go into the variable (by default) unless you tell it to. `var=$(output_only_to_stderr)` will be empty - `var=$(output_only_to_stderr 2>&1)` will not.

Comment: Dennis, thanks. This is correct, I was thinking something opposite (I was trying to capture the stderr as you have shown. I will fix that in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a sample script for MySQL, but it can be easily edited for Oracle :

```
#!/bin/bash

remote=oracle@5.6.7.8

ssh -q -t $remote <<EOF
bash <<EOFBASH
mysql <<ENDOFSQL>/tmp/out
show databases;
ENDOFSQL
EOFBASH
EOF

scp $remote:/tmp/out /tmp/out
ds=$(</tmp/out)

cat <<EOF
START OUTPUT
$ds
END OUTPUT
EOF

rm /tmp/out
```

Tested, works well. Instead of using `su - oracle`, try to ssh directly to oracle user ;)

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the input, will try this out as well as an alternate method.